# How to Query for dupe leads in Bulk with Mapping?

Tags: apex, soql, bulkification

Goal: 'Bulkify' the existing Apex trigger used for counting how many dupes a Lead had, and inserting the Contact Id of the Contact record (if more than one, the first in the list) that matched the email address of the Lead.

Here's a snippet of the code I want to bulkify:

```
for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        //Make sure our lead has an email address
        if (l.Email != null) {
            //Find a dupe
            String leadEmail = l.Email;
            List<Lead> dupeLeads = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Email = :leadEmail];

            //If a dupe is found, update a field
            if (dupeLeads.size() > 0) {
                l.Dupe_Lead_Counter__c = dupeLeads.size();
            } else {
                //0 would designate a true unique
                l.Dupe_Lead_Counter__c = 0;
            }
```

So, this is clearly violating the mandate of 'No SOQL queries in For() loops.'

Reading the various doucmentation and tutorials, it looks as though the pattern needs to be a List of the sObjects we want to query from (all Leads with email values in this case) and then use mapping to somehow map the lists of dupe Leads (by email) with the master Lead email list.

How do I even group duplicate emails into a List without creating a For() loop/SOQL query in the first place?

This is what I have so far:

```
Set<String> leadsWithEmails = new Set<String>();
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        if(l.email != null) {
            leadsWithEmails.add(l.Email);
        }
    }
    //Query for all Leads
    List<Lead> potentialDupeLeads = [SELECT Id,Email FROM Lead
                                    WHERE Email IN :leadsWithEmails];

    //Step 3: Make a map that lets you search for Leads by Email
    Map<String, Lead> emailToLeadMap = new Map<String, Lead>();
    for (Lead l : potentialDupeLeads) {
        emailToLeadMap.put(l.Email, l);
    }
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson testing it thanks! Btw, when you created the Set<String> lead Emails, why is there a `z` in `new Set<z String>();`

Comment: Mobile formatting ftw.

Comment: @AdrianLarson just clarifying-- is that `z` intentional?

Comment: @AdrianLarson good stuff, I am encountering an error:  `Invalid foreign key relationship`  this statement is tripping it up: `record.Lead.Dupe_Lead_Counter__c = count;`

Comment: Did the updated answer resolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregate queries for this.

```
Set<String> leadEmails = new Set<String>();
for (Lead record : trigger.new)
    leadEmails.add(record.Email);

Map<String, Integer> emailCounts = new Map<String, Integer>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT Email, count(Id) records
    FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :leadEmails
    GROUP BY Email
])
    emailCounts.put((String)aggregate.get('Email'), (Integer)aggregate.get('records'));

for (Lead record : trigger.new)
{
    Integer count = emailCounts.containsKey(record.Email) ?
        emailCounts.get(record.Email) : 0;
    record.Dupe_Lead_Counter__c = count;
}
```

Comment: thanks! Sorry for belated reply, just to be clear-- you created this code to augment my starting point, or is there original code I have that needs to be stripped? Trying to track with your additions

Comment: @GPP This would replace what you have entirely. Note that the counts above do not include the leads from the transaction itself, which you probably also want to count. Not that you are updating those matching records...

Comment: thanks for the quick reply (pretty sure that's a world record!) So I would effectively wrap this snippet of code in my Lead Trigger code, correct? 'trigger CountDupeLeads on Lead (before insert, before update) {}'

Comment: @GPP Yeah you would wrap it in that. FYI you can in-line format code with `\`` characters.

Comment: thanks for the tip! Just scanning the code, it looks this snippet `for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
     SELECT Email, count(Id) records
     FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :leadEmails
     GROUP BY Email
 ])` is referencing the bound variable `:leadEmails` which has not previously been defined if we're just running with the snippet of code. Does some of the previous code need to be repurposed?

Comment: Oh yeah I can add that but just build a set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41136/discussion-between-gpp-and-adrian-larson).